# How do I evaluate python special functions at complex values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, complex-numbers

I need to evaluate the special function *K(x)*, where *K* is `scipy.special.ellipk(x)`, for  complex valued inputs, *-x*.

Simply trying to evaluate this (at say `0.1 + 1j`)gives me an error. Is there a way I can evaluate this function for complex values with numpy/scipy support?

Comment: Do you mean `0.1 + 1 * j`?

Comment: @IanAuld: `0.1+1j` is valid complex number syntax in Python.

Comment: Here is a related scipy bug: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/1431 .  It seems that what you want is not currently implemented in scipy.

Comment: There are other libraries you could use which support it (e.g. `mpmath`: `mpmath.ellipk(0.1+1j) == mpc(real='1.4379563993242519', imag='0.3175211751894505')`.